# discord.js Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'voiceChannel' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typeerror, discord

```
else if (m.content.startsWith(config.prefix + 'voteskip' && (client.guildMember.voiceChannel.connection() === guild.user.voiceChannel.connection())))
```

Hi there, this code above is designed to compare the voice channels of the bot and the user who uses the command *voteskip. However when someone uses the command, it gives the full error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'voiceChannel' of undefined

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

This JavaScript error means that `client.guildMember` is `undefined` i.e. not set, thus you can't get any properties for something that isn't defined or set.

You're probably making too strong an assumption that client has a guild member (whatever that is). Check that the `client.guildMember` is defined (e.g. `client.guildMember !== undefined`), otherwise handle the case when it is not.